# Is maximum function distributive over addition

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

How can I show whether or not maximum is distributive over addition. Hence, basically I have to check the following
$\max(Cy + Dz) = \max(Cy) + \max(Dz)$, where $C$, $D$ are matrices and, $y$, $z$ are column vectors.

Comment: Dont think uniform distribution is an appropriate tag here. Linear Algebra is a much better choice

Comment: What's the ordering on column vectors here? Lexicographic order?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by max

Comment: Max is a function that returns the element that has the maximum value from the given vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming C and D are mxn matrices over $\mathbb R$? That would place y and z in $\mathbb R^n$. The max function sends vectors to their max-valued component? You didn't specify the context you're dealing in; but this seems like something from intro linear algebra; so I'll proceed accordingly:

It's not that bad really. I just started visualizing it in my head and it seemed fishy; so I decided I should try to find a counter example. Actually, I wasn't even convinced the vector sum was additive, let alone whether the sum of matrix vector products were. Matrix and matrix-vector multiplication annoy me, so I decided I'd reduce it to the case of vector sums by taking m=n=5, C=D=$I_5$, with $I_5$= the identity matrix (the one with a top-down-left to right diagonal of 1's and each other entry 0), and taking y=(1,2,3,5,4),z=(7,8,9,1,2).  I chose $I_5$ for both C and D because I knew it would leave y and z unchanged and make the computations easier by reducing it to the vector sum.

$\max(Cy + Dz) =\max((1,2,3,5,4)+(7,8,9,1,2)=\max(8,10,12,6,6)=12$
$\max(Cy) + \max(Dz)=\max(1,2,3,5,4)+\max(7,8,9,1,2)=5+9=14$; and

$12\neq14$.

Tip:

See how I took advantage of what I knew about the structure of the objects I was dealing with to construct an easier counterexample? You should always try to do things like that; it makes things easier, and keeps you in touch with the properties of the objects you're dealing with when you're constantly using each property as you think about relationships among the objects. You will quickly develop an uncanny sense of intuition about the subject.